# Retain input focus in autocomplete on meteor js

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, meteor

I've added https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-autocomplete to a meteor js project and can get a list of available options. I'm using the arrow up- and down-keys to mark my entry and enter to select it. But then the cursor moves out of focus from the input field so I can't press enter again to submit the form. I have to click the button on the form to perform the submit.


html:

```
<div class="controls">
  {{> inputAutocomplete settings=settings id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" }}
</div>
```

I added focus to the js file but it only helps before I select an item from the list:

```
Template.raceAddParticipant.rendered = function () {
  document.getElementById("name").focus();
};
```

How can I circumvent this?

regards Claus

Answer (score 0):

(I wrote this package.)

I'm guessing you're using autocomplete in single-field mode. I implemented in this feature to prevent the popup menu from staying open after a selection was made. By default, the popup menu stays open whenever the field is focused (and there is a match), and the enter button makes a selection.

Do you have a suggestion for how this behavior could be improved? If so, perhaps you should open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I'm in single-field mode. What would be nice is to have the cursor at the end of the text like in this typeahead demo: http://typeahead.meteor.com/. This way you only need to press enter once more to submit the form.

Comment: @kometen I can't access that site right now, but all I'm saying is that if the cursor stays at the end of the text and the field is focused, then the autocomplete menu will stay open, and it will capture the Enter event. We could have it close, but then any other keystroke would just cause it to open again. Why can't the user just tab into the submit button?

Comment: Thank you for your time. I ended up using jquerys automcomplete with a functioncall in Template.raceAddParticipant.rendered to mongodb using a regexp. This returns an array that I then use in the form using a type=hidden. js-file: https://github.com/kometen/karusselrenn/blob/master/client/views/races/race_add_participant.js